# Multiple applications under single domain, in corresponding folders

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

This is a bit unusual, but somewhat reasonable. I have a domain say `mycompany.com` and a sub domain `demos.mycompany.com` and I want to host some demo applications under this sub domain.

So I created a website in IIS (7.5) say `demos.mycompany`, and added 2 applications to it named `demo1` and `demo2` which contains a different website application, and they can be accessed via `demos.mycompany/demo1` and `demos.mycompany/demo2`. The root website (`demos.mycompany.com`) loads correctly and works fine. But the problem is for `demo1` which is an asp.net web api project. The problem occurs when a request to web services is made, for example `demos.mycompany/api/Account/UserInfo` is not found because the project base URL is changed to `demos.mycompany/demo1` and therefore the mentioned web service is available at `demos.mycompany/demo1/api/Account/UserInfo`.

I don't know if there will be other problems with this approach. This was just the one big problem that I found, There may be other shortcomings to this.

1. Are there any suggestions to solve this problem?
2. Is there any other issues to consider before going on with this approach?